# SoapUI error with Yii generated WSDL

Tags: php, web-services, yii, wsdl, soapui

I have a Yii web service. The WSDL is automatically generated, but I get errors when using SoapUI to test them.

Here is an example of the error I get :

```
Mon Sep 02 17:24:53 CEST 2013:ERROR:org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: union value 'unbounded' does not match any members of 'type of maxOccurs attribute in xs:narrowMaxMin'
```

I indeed have a 1-N relation like this :

```
/**
 * @var Foo[]  Foos {nillable=true, minOccurs=0, maxOccurs=unbounded}
 * @soap
 */
public $foos;
```

As far as I know `maxOccurs=unbounded` should be correct, so what's wrong with it?

Cheers!

Comment: The error says it all: It has a problem with your union value of `unbounded`.

Comment: @cale_b "O RLY?" is a bit outdated, and I'm a bit too old to say "Duh!" , but thanks for your contribution...

Comment: @cale_b sorry if I seemed rude...

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide more detailed example of your generated wsdl? You may get this error, for example, if "foo" element lies inside xs:all tag - it specifies that each child element can occur zero or one time so maxOccurs value must be 1. This problem is solved by putting element inside xs:sequence tag instead of xs:all that enables "unbounded" value for maxOccurs.

Answer (score 0):

Allright, got it!

The attribute `$foos` is actually not `unbounded` : it is an array of `Foo`, but as an attribute, it appears only 0 or 1 time... So no `unbounded`, but `1` in `maxOccurs` :

```
/**
 * @var Foo[]  Foos {nillable=true, minOccurs=0, maxOccurs=1}
 * @soap
 */
public $foos;
```

Yay!